# How to break a master list into multiple list of size two

Tags: java, salesforce, apex

I have a requirement of merging duplicates in salesforce. Merge operation takes duplicates only upto 2. So i want to break the list( if it has elements more than 2) into multiple smaller lists of size 2 and perform merge operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use third party libraries, this is a one line job.

**using Guava:**

**import:** `import com.google.common.collect.Lists;`

```
Lists.partition(list, 2);
```

**Using Apache common collections**:

**import:** `import org.apache.commons.collections4.ListUtils;`

```
ListUtils.partition(list, 2)
```

Let me know if you don't want to use third party libraries, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you could bulkify your merge but you could do the following to break the list down:

```
Integer count = 0;
List<List<SOBJECT>> lists = new List<List<SOBJECT>> (); 
for (SOBJECT record : LIST) {

    if (count == 0) {
        List<SOBJECT> toAdd = new List<SOBJECT> ()
    }        

    if (count < 2) {
        toAdd.add (record);
        count++;
    } else {
        lists.add (toAdd);
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Mind you this is just off the top of my head and I'm certain there are better solutions!